# How do I md5sum all files in /bin and sub directories and verify the hash using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, hashsum

I tried with

```
find /bin -type -f -exec md5sum {} + >>sum.md5
```

The `/bin` directory contains a variety of files types, but the above  returns the checksums for only regular files. Is there any way to find *all files* in and under `/bin`, run `md5sum`  on them,  and verify the checksums?

Here's the detail of what I want to achieve. We take the backup of the `/bin` and its subdirectories and md5sum all the files into an `old.md5` file, tar it and upload to cloud. For example I had a crash in my system then I downloaded the `/bin` directory from the cloud and restore in, and again run the md5sum command to generate a `new.md5` with hashes of all files. Now I want to compare the `new.md5` file and `old.md5` file to make sure no changes have takken to the file during download or upload. The script should verify the hashes.

I need a script for the entire thing.

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Your command does indeed also descend into subdirectories. It is not clear from your question if you are fine with the results from this first step. Are you just asking how to perform a check based on the `sum.md5` file you generated?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "_all files_" that your command doesn't already do. What's the problem? Are you hitting a permissions issue? You don't say

Comment: @roaima "all files" in the sense all type of files like regular file character file block file etc.

Comment: character files and block files are actually devices. There shouldn't be any of those under `/bin`

Comment: @roaima I am looking  for a script which checks the hash of all files in /bin and its sub directories and verify the hash is correct and no changes have made to file. I tried with " tree /bin | md5sum -c output.md5 " note: output.md5 is the hash file. It is not able to read the files in sub directories and i am not able to find the logic to verify and confirm if the hash has changed or not in bash scripting

Comment: Your code already creates a file containing hashes for all the regular files. As fra-san asked in the first comment, "_Are you just asking how to perform a check based on the sum.md5 file you generated?_"

Comment: @roaima Sorry my english bit weak but i will try to explain in detail what is that i need. We take the backup of the /bin and its sub dir and also md5sum all the files and create the old.md5 file  and tar it and upload to cloud. For example i had a crash in my system then i down the /bin from the cloud and restore in and again run the md5sum command to generate a new.md5 with hashes of all files. Now i want to compare the new .md5 file and old.md5 file and make sure no changes have takken to the file during download or upload. The script should verify the hashes. need script to entire part.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. I've added that ↑ to the question so it's easily visible to everyone. (And your English is just fine.)

Answer (score 2):

To find all non-directory files using `find`, use a test that weeds out directories:

```
find -H /bin ! -type d -exec md5sum {} + >sum.md5
```

This will run `md5sum` in batches on as many files as possible, including symbolic links, while avoiding giving the utility directories (which would make it issue a warning).

The `-H` option to `find` makes it resolve any symbolic links given on the command line, i.e. `/bin` (if that's a symbolic link).

To verify the calculated checksums, use `md5sum -c sum.md5`.

Answer (score 1):

Your command already descends into subdirectories (unless `/bin` is a link, see below) but it will skip links and other non-regular files because you are explicitly telling `find` to only return regular files. That's what `-type f` means. From `man find`:

```
   -type c
          File is of type c:

          f      regular file
```

To find everything, just remove the `-type`:

```
find /bin/ -exec md5sum {} + >>sum.md5
```

Note the `/` at the end of `/bin/`: that is needed in case your `/bin` is a symlink (as it often is a symlink to `/usr/bin` on modern Linux systems). Without it, the command will only return the symlink itself (`/bin`) and will not descend into subdirectories.

If you later want to verify these checksums, just run:

```
md5sum -c sum.md5
```

Comment: @terdon  Thanks for the input i am trying to restore the /bin and contents in a remote server only restore if the md5sum is correct do you have any script to verify the md5sum and restore only if it is ok .

Comment: @DilipRao that is a different question. If you run `md5sum -c sum.md5`, that will report whether the checksum matched, so you can use that output to restore. If you need help with that, please ask a new question, giving an example `sum.md5` command and the script you have so far.

Comment: @DilipRao You mean you want to restore the files that have _failing_ checksums? It sounds like you'd be better off just running `rsync` from a known good system, or make the local system's package manager reinstall the affected packages.  This is, as terdon points out, quite a different question though.

Comment: It sounds like a reimplementation of [tripwire](https://github.com/Tripwire/tripwire-open-source)

Comment: @terdon find /etc ! -type d -exec md5sum {} + >>iutput.md5  give output as md5sum it is a directory " Any other way to md5sum for all files in all sub directories.

Comment: @DilipRao this _does_ look at all files in all subdirectories.

Comment: @ terdon do you have any altenative code which do work for all types of files in all dir in /bin i need to md5sum all the files in the /bin and verify it .

Comment: @dilip I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. This command does work for all types of files and I have also given the command to verify. If it doesn't work for you, please edit your question and explain what happens when you try it.